Not able to use Opensearch action from IOT core
I am trying to recieve logs in a mqtt topic from IOT core by attaching a OpensearchAction  to it to log it in opensearch topic. I have created a IOT rule with query SELECT * FROM 'device/+/log' and attached a IAM role that has AmazonOpenSearchServiceFullAccess  policy attached. I have also added the trust relationship in the IAM role as follows:
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::7..5:user/xyz@email.com",
                "Service": "iot.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}

I have also attached a Cloudwatch action. I am able to see the logs in the MQTT console  and cloudwatch but not in Opensearch topic. I added the logs for MQTT and i am seeing a Forboidden error in the IOT logs. Here is the error:
{
    "timestamp": "2024-07-03 04:52:03.991",
    "logLevel": "ERROR",
    "traceId": "48..aba9",
    "accountId": "7...5",
    "status": "Failure",
    "eventType": "RuleExecution",
    "clientId": "N/A",
    "topicName": "xyz/4434/abc",
    "ruleName": "myrule",
    "ruleAction": "OpenSearchAction",
    "resources": {
        "Endpoint": "https://my-endpoint.ap-south-1.es.amazonaws.com",
        "Index": "mylogs",
        "Type": "_doc",
        "DocumentId": "my-logs123"
    },
    "principalId": "AIDA3FlDT6YB6WARZKZ7W",
    "details": "Forbidden"
}

I have also added the arn of the IAM role to backend mapping in Opensearch security > role > all_access > Map User
Additionally, I have followed all instructions in text
I am able to push logs to the topic from my local but the IOT core is not able to send it using Opensearch Action. Forbidden indicates some permission issue.
Any help on what I am missing here.
